# Adding entry to dropdown field in gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, dropdown

What i want to achieve is to populate a form field with data previously stored in the database by a previous form. More specifically a dropdown list that loads a set of values that have been stored by the entries of a previous form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a snippet I wrote that helps you do this.

https://gist.github.com/spivurno/9707874

You can add a plugin header to this and install as a plugin or install as a snippet via a snippet manager like [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/).

You'll need to configure this to target your desired form and field and also modify the query args to populate the entries you want. You'll see a note next to each parameter letting you know what it does.